# How to create multicolor rasterized picture in processing

Tags: java, processing

I followed this tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XO8u0Y75FRk), and I have successfully added colors to the black and white picture. However, my intention was to create a multi-color or gradient effect (like [here](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/18376/how-do-i-create-a-gradient-filled-shape-on-a-gradient-background) or [here](https://processing.org/examples/lineargradient.html)) instead of switching colors when I move the cursor.

I very new at processing, and I have tried to play with the variable, with no success.

Here is the code snippet of the sketch:
`

```
PImage img;

void setup() {
  size(598,336);
  colorMode(HSB);
  img = loadImage("picture-in-data-folder.jpg");
  img.resize(598,336);
  //ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  frameRate(30);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  

//  fill(0);
  
  float tiles = mouseX/10;
  float tileSize = width/tiles;
  
// color section 

  fill(color(tiles, 255, 255));
  tileSize++;
  if (tiles > width / 2) {
    tileSize = 0;
  } 

// end color section

  translate(tileSize/2, tileSize/2);
  
  for (int x = 0; x < tiles; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < tiles; y++) {
      
      color c = img.get(int(x*tileSize),int(y*tileSize));
      float size = map(brightness(c), 0, 255, tileSize, 0);
      
    ellipse(x*tileSize, y*tileSize, size, size);
  // image(img, mouseX, mouseY);
    }
  }
}
```

I would be grateful if you had any hints, or if you could provide an advice.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you already have the mouse changing the number of tiles. Are you simply looking at rendering each ellipse a radial gradient ?

Comment: My intention is to colorize the whole set of tiles into one gradient color

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to put a `fill()` command inside the `for` loop.

Long answer:

Right now, your code is doing the following:

1. Define `tiles` based on `mouseX`
2. Set the fill color to `(tiles, 255, 255)`
3. Draw all the circles

I think what you want it to do is something like this:

1. Set the fill color to `(21, 255, 255)` (or whatever you want the first color to be)
2. draw the first circle
3. set the fill color to the next color in the gradient
4. draw the second circle
5. etc.

In order to do this, you need to put a command into the `for` loop which changes the fill color. Here is one way to do that:

```
for (int x = 0; x < tiles; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < tiles; y++) {
    color c = img.get(int(x*tileSize),int(y*tileSize));
    float size = map(brightness(c), 0, 255, tileSize, 0);

    fill(map(x, 0, tiles, 0, 255), 255, 255);
    ellipse(x*tileSize, y*tileSize, size, size);
  }
}
```

I just added that fill command as a function of `x`, but you can make it whatever you want. In order for it to be a gradient, it needs to vary somewhat with `x` or `y`.